# Adding lazy delete method to Binary Search Tree - java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, lazy-evaluation

The code below is what I already have, and I need to add a lazy deletion method. Basically the lazy deletion method marks a node for deletion, rather than deleting it. In this way, deleted locations are treated as empty when inserting and as occupied during a search. I'm assuming that a boolean in the node would be the easiest way, but I am struggling to figure out how to configure the methods to take into account if the node has been "lazyDeleted" or not. I've posted the code below. Thanks in advance.

```
/**
 * Binary Search Trees are binary trees with search functionality on the order of lg(N)
 *     (lg() is the logarithm of base 2, and N is the number of elements processed)
 * 
 * Binary Search Trees contain a root node that has exactly two child nodes of the same type
 *     These nodes are initially set to null but can be changed later
 * The Binary Tree has a root node, with everything that is larger than the root contained in
 *     the right subtree, and everything smaller than the root contained in the left subtree
 * 
 * @author Mark Allen Weiss (originally)
 *
 * @param <E> any element that is a subclass of Comparable
 */
public class BinarySearchTree<E extends Comparable<? super E>> {

    /*-----------------------*
     * Variable Declarations *
     *-----------------------*/
    private BinaryNode<E> root;

    /**
     * Constructs a tree with an empty root
     */
    public BinarySearchTree() {
        root = null;
    }

    /**
     * Releases the root of the tree, rendering it empty
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public void makeEmpty() {
        root = null;
    }

    /**
     * Checks to see if the tree is empty
     * 
     * @return <tt>true</tt> if the tree is empty; <tt>false</tt> otherwise
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return root == null;
    }

    /**
     * Searches the tree to see if it contains the specified element
     * 
     * @param element the element to be found
     * @return <tt>true</tt> if the element is found; <tt>false</tt> otherwise
     */
    public boolean contains(E element) {
        return contains(element, root);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the smallest element in the tree
     * 
     * @return the smallest element in the tree
     */
    public E findMin() {
        if(isEmpty()) {
            // throw new UnderflowException();
            return null;
            /* The author throws a new UnderflowException, but the class is not included in the
             * standard Java API, so I return a null instead */
        } else {
            return findMin(root).element;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds the largest element in the tree
     * 
     * @return the largest element in the tree
     */
    public E findMax() {
        if(isEmpty()) {
            // throw new UnderflowException();
            return null;
            /* The author throws a new UnderflowException, but the class is not included in the
             * standard Java API, so I return a null instead */
        } else {
            return findMax(root).element;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the given element into the tree
     * 
     * @param element
     * @return void
     */
    public void insert(E element) {
        root = insert(element, root);
    }

    /**
     * Removes the specified element from the tree
     * 
     * @param element the element to be removed
     * @return void
     */
    public void remove(E element) {
        root = remove(element, root);
    }

    /**
     * Prints the tree contents in sorted order
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public void printTree() {
        if(isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Empty Tree");
        } else {
            printTree(root);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to compute height of a subtree.
     *
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree
     */
    private int height(BinaryNode<E> t) {
        if( t == null ) {
         return -1;
        } else {
         return 1 + Math.max( height( t.left ), height( t.right ) ); 
        }
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to find an item in a subtree 
     * 
     * @param element the item to search for
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree
     * @return <tt>true</tt> if the item is found; <tt>false</tt> otherwise
     */
    private boolean contains(E element, BinaryNode<E> t) {
        if(t == null) {
            return false;
        }

        int compareResult = element.compareTo(t.element);

        if(compareResult < 0) {
            return contains(element, t.left);
        } else if(compareResult > 0) {
            return contains(element, t.right);
        } else {
            return true; // Match
        }
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to find the smallest item in a subtree
     * 
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree
     * @return the node containing the smallest item
     */
    private BinaryNode<E> findMin(BinaryNode<E> t) {
        if(t == null) {
            return null;
        } else if(t.left == null) {
            return t;
        } else {
            return findMin(t.left);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to find the largest item in a subtree
     * 
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree
     * @return the node containing the largest item
     */
    private BinaryNode<E> findMax(BinaryNode<E> t) {
        if(t == null) {
            return null;
        } else if(t.right == null) {
            return t;
        } else {
            return findMax(t.right);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to insert into a subtree
     *     Duplicates are not allowed and ignored
     *     
     * @param element the item to insert
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree
     * @return the new root of the subtree
     */
    private BinaryNode<E> insert(E element, BinaryNode<E> t) {
        if(t == null) {
            return new BinaryNode<E>(element);
        }

        int compareResult = element.compareTo(t.element);

        if(compareResult < 0) {
            t.left = insert(element, t.left);
        } else if(compareResult > 0) {
            t.right = insert(element, t.right);
        } else {
            ; // Duplicate; do nothing
        }

        return t;
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to remove an element from a subtree
     * 
     * @param element the element to be removed
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree
     * @return the new root of the subtree
     */
    private BinaryNode<E> remove(E element, BinaryNode<E> t) {
        if(t == null) {
            return t; // Item not found; do nothing
        }

        int compareResult = element.compareTo(t.element);

        if(compareResult < 0) {
            t.left = remove(element, t.left);
        } else if(compareResult > 0) {
            t.right = remove(element, t.right);
        } else if(t.left != null && t.right != null) { // Two children
            t.element =  findMin(t.right).element;
            t.right = remove(t.element, t.right);
        } else {
            t = (t.left != null) ? t.left : t.right;
        }

        return t;
    }

    /**
     * Internal method to print a subtree in sorted order
     * 
     * @param t the node that roots the subtree
     * @return void
     */
    private void printTree(BinaryNode<E> t) {
        if(t != null){
            printTree(t.left);
            System.out.println(t.element);
            printTree(t.right);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Internal class that defines a tree node with exactly two children
     * 
     * @author Mark Allen Weiss
     * 
     * @param <E> any element that is a subclass of Comparable
     */
    private static class BinaryNode<E> {

        /*-----------------------*
         * Variable Declarations *
         *-----------------------*/
        E element; // The data in the node
        BinaryNode<E> left; // The left child node
        BinaryNode<E> right; // The right child node

        /**
         * Constructs a new BinaryNode of type E that contains the given element
         * 
         * @param theElement the data to be stored in the node
         */
        BinaryNode(E theElement) {
            this(theElement, null, null);
        }

        /**
         * Constructs a new BinaryNode of type E that contains the given element and has the
         *     given nodes as its left and right children respectively
         * 
         * @param theElement the data to be stored in the node
         * @param leftChild the left child of the node
         *            (either a leaf node or a subtree)
         * @param rightChild the right child of the node
         *            (either a leaf node or a subtree)
         */
        BinaryNode(E theElement, BinaryNode<E> leftChild, BinaryNode<E> rightChild) {
            element = theElement;
            left = leftChild;
            right = rightChild;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a 

    public void lazyDeletion(E element){
     lazyDeletion(element, root).lazyDelete = true;
    }

Basically functions just like remove except instead of setting the root to null, it sets the lazyDelete boolean to true for the node found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is add a boolean to your TreeNodes and set that to false (or true depending on how you designed it) instead of removing it from the tree. I handled insert by simply resetting the deleted property of that node.